# XML concatenation : how to concatenate nodes with markup tags not just values with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, concatenation, batch-processing

I have the following XML for batch processing by a web service which simply does basic arithmetic operations. During processing, some nodes will fail, for example, because of illegal arguments such as those causing division by zero (in the example the 3rd node). I need to create a separate XML document concatenating these offending nodes, or those which will fail for some other reason. I cannot come up with a proper XPATH method to concatenate the XML fragments.

The source XML:

```
<Envelopes>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fc="http://fc.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fc:add>
         <arg0>99938</arg0>
         <arg1>62</arg1>
      </fc:add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fc="http://fc.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fc:addaaaaaaaaaa>
         <arg0>34</arg0>
         <arg1>223</arg1>
      </fc:addaaaaaaaaaa>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fc="http://fc.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fc:divide>
         <arg0>634</arg0>
         <arg1>0</arg1>
      </fc:divide>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fc="http://fc.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fc:subtract>
         <arg0>3400</arg0>
         <arg1>2200</arg1>
      </fc:subtract>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</Envelopes>
```

XSL transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet version=
"1.0" xmlns:xsl=
"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp=xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="/Envelopes/soapenv:Envelope">

<!-- introduce a variable for the current envelope -->
<xsl:variable name="fc" select="."/>

<!--  I NEED TO CONCAT THE ENTIRE NODE TO CREATE A BRAND NEW XML FILE -->

<xsl:variable name="addEnvelope" select="'&lt;Envelopes&gt;',."/>
   <xsl:message terminate="no" dp:priority="notice">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$addEnvelope"/>
</xsl:message>
<!-- I SEE THE OUTPUT <Envelopes>324 0  etc... WHAT I WANT IS TO GET AN OUTPUT LIKE: -->
<Envelopes><soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:fc="http://fc.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fc:multiply>
         <arg0>34</arg0>
         <arg1>2</arg1>
      </fc:multiply>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>  etc...

</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Other than `fc:divide/arg1=0`, what are the criteria for selecting the "offending" envelopes (assuming you mean "envelopes" when you say "nodes")?

Comment: It might help a lot if you show a sample of the XML you are currently expecting to be output too. Thanks!

Comment: @user3016153 yes I mean the envelopes, selection criteria is negligible as I'm not asking how to select, I'm asking how to concatenate.

Comment: @TimC it's already at the end of the code - the last part after the comment

Comment: @user3016153 the second node will also cause an error, for example as the web operation call should be add not addaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: @fledglingCoder I don't think you understand the nature of your problem: you *do* need to **select** the envelopes you are interested in, and tell your stylesheet to copy them into the result tree. That way they will end up "concatenated" in the output (although that is not the correct term to use here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is a bit vague, it is hard to give an exact answer, but I would suggest you need to be building on top of the [XSLT identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

In XSLT, you don't 'concatenate' nodes, that is something you do to strings, but you do copy elements, or create new ones, to the output tree. The identity template above, on its own, copies all nodes in the document to the output tree. By doing this, this means all you really need to do is add templates to handle nodes you want to change, or in your case, add a template to stop nodes being copied.

For example, you mention about division by zero. Suppose you wanted to create XML containing only the **envelope** elements where **arg1** is zero. This means, when used in conjunction with the XSLT identity template, all you need it a template to ignore **envelope** elements where **arg1** is not zero.

```
<xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope[not(soapenv:Body/fc:divide/arg1 = '0')]" />
```

And that's it! Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:fc="http://fc.org/">
  <xsl:output method="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope[not(soapenv:Body/fc:divide/arg1 = '0')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if you would rather explicitly select the **Envelope** elements you want to copy, as opposed to you want to copy, you could create a template to match the **Envelopes** element, and then use **xsl:apply-templates** to select the ones you want.

This XSLT should work too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:fc="http://fc.org/">
  <xsl:output method="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Envelopes">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="soapenv:Envelope[soapenv:Body/fc:divide/arg1 = '0']" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```